# How can I obtain the response signal for this question?

Tags: z-transform, homework, transfer-function

[image]

In particular I am having trouble with 6b).

From what I understand, we can split a difference LTI equation into two sums, the sum of the previous responses, and the sum of the previous inputs.
Something like this:

[image]

Now to get a zero-state response, I have to zero out the first part of the formula. This I understand.

So to get the zero-state **step** response, I must use `x[n] = u[n]` and zero out all past outputs of the system.

The problem I'm having is deriving `y[n]` in the first place.

I have had a couple ideas, however am not confident in their correctness:

- Since `H(z) = Y(z)/X(z)` I could compare the given `H(z)` to `Y(z)(1 - 1/z)` because that's the z-transform of 1/u[n]. Correct me if I'm wrong. Then I could make Y subject of the formula and figure out
  the    inverse transform from there.
- I thought about using convolution with the inverse transform of
  `H(z)` and input signal `u[n]`.

However I'm not convinced these are correct because nowhere am I "enforcing" the definition of zero-ing out the previous outputs.

Any guidelines would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

The (zero-state) step response is just the cumulative sum of the impulse response $h[n]$:

$$y_{ZS}[n]=u[n]\sum_{k=0}^nh[k]$$

This follows in a straightforward manner from the convolution of a unit step $u[n]$ with the impulse response:

$$y_{ZS}[n]=(h\star u)[n]$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating further on how to obtain the first statement? Particularly I don't understand how this relates to being the "zero state". I understand the use of the convolution sum, but not how it relates to the zero state. Thank you :)

Comment: @Novicegrammer: By definition, the impulse response $h[n]$ is the "zero-state" response to an impulse. So any "zero-state" response is obtained by convolving the respective input signal with the impulse response.